# Cosa significa "azzinnare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Era un ambulante. Si avvicinava trascinandosi dietro un organetto, che sulle irregolarità del terreno esalava, di tanto in tanto, una nota. Non potete stare qui, piccerelli, disse, sfoderando un sorriso amichevole. Dopo il tramonto il parco chiude, se vi trovano gli sbirri vi portano in prigione. Siete appena arrivati? chiese, mettendosi a sedere accanto a loro. Sí, rispose Vita, con orgoglio. Stamattina, col traghetto dall’isola. Abbiamo visto tutta la città. Siete soli? Sí, disse Vita, e **azzinnò** un’occhiatina complice a Diamante.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "azzinnare" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo verbo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine dialettale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come si può leggere in questo blog di [Riflessioni sul dialetto](http://www.isolamena.com/Caccuri/Dialetto/Riflessioni/Riflessioni.htm), *azzinnare* o meglio *zinnare* significa ammiccare, fare l'occhiolino, strizzare l'occhio:

> **Zinnare**
>
> Il verbo dialettale zinnare, da non confondere con quello italiano che
> significa tutt'altra cosa, è diffuso in tutto il meridione e indica
> l'ammiccamento, l'azione del fare l'occhiolino, strizzare l'occhio. Il
> verbo zinnare è usato magicamente in un verso della celeberrima "O
> guarracino" (fece n'uocchio a zennariello a lo sperduto
> 'nnammoratiello), una stupenda canzone di anonimo popolare di fine
> '700 interpretata da artisti del calibro di Roberto Murolo, Fausto
> Cigliano, La nuova compagnia di canto popolare, Sergio Bruni ed altri
> mostri sacri della canzone napoletana.